# My JavaScript function does one thing when it gets the wrong input

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that's meant to get media playing status from a GET request and do something accordingly depending on whether the media returns playing or not.

My function:

```
function get_media() {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_media')
    .then(function(resp) { return resp.json() }) // Convert data to json
    .then(function(data) {
        var songTitle = data.title
        var artist = data.artist
        var playingStatus = data.playing
        console.log(playingStatus)
        if (playingStatus = "true") {
            console.log("playing")
            document.getElementById("play").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("pause").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('song-title').innerHTML = songTitle;
            document.getElementById('artist-name').innerHTML = artist;
        } 
        if (playingStatus = "false") {
            console.log("paused")
            document.getElementById("play").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("pause").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('song-title').innerHTML = songTitle;
            document.getElementById('artist-name').innerHTML = artist;
        }
    })
}
```

The issue is, even if `playingStatus` is set to false, the function still does the action specified in `if (playingStatus = "true")`, as shown in this screenshot below of the console.

[image]

The console tells me `playingStatus` is set to false, but is activating the wrong condition in the if statement. Why is this happening?

Comment: By doing `playingStatus = "false"`, you're assigning the `string "false"` to `playingStatus`. To test for equality, use `==`

Comment: Use `===` for comparison. Single `=` is assignment

Answer (score 3):

#### Short answer:

By doing `playingStatus = "true"` you're *assigning a value to playingStatus*, not comparing it against the value. If you want to test whether it's a particular value you should use `===` or `==`, as in `playingStatus === "true"`.

#### Why `if (playingStatus = "true")` is always true:

Because an assignment expression [evaluates to the assigned value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment), the expression `playingStatus = "true"` will evaluate to "true", and because "true" is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), the condition `if (playingStatus = "true")` will always be true.

#### String vs boolean:

Another possible issue is that `true` and `false` may not be strings, so you might need to lose the quotes, e.g. `playingStatus === true`.

Answer (score 0):

Right, sorry, it turns out I was using `=` instead of `==` in my if statement. It should've been `if (playingStatus == "false")` not `if (playingStatus = "false")`.

Still curious why the first statement returned true, though.

Comment: The assignment of `"true"` to `playingStatus` is truthy